# Полосы на экране Dell n5050

Tags: железо, ноутбук, dell

Ноутбук Dell n5050, появились артефакты на экране. Если выводить изображение на внешний монитор, то там всё в порядке. Склоняюсь к тому, что это проблема с шлейфом, но хотелось бы знать какие ещё могут быть варианты ?
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: 95% что это проблема со шлейфом. У меня похожее было.

Comment: Если медленно открывать\закрывать крышку - эффект меняется?

Comment: Нет, не меняется

Comment: Тоже есть похожее. При этом у меня ещё не терминальная стадия: можно чуть приоткрыть крышку или попробовать нажать в определённом месте, то экран становится нормальным, а через минуту может снова начать потихоньку гаснуть такими полосами. Бывает ли от других проблем -- не могу сказать.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно что это все таки проблема со шлейфом. 1. У меня похожее было. Когда поменял. Все норм стало. 2. Когда Вы подключаете монитор, то на мониторе все норм. Значит это не видеокарта. И логично предположить что проблема где то начиная от шлейфа к матрице. И отсюда выплывает еще что это может быть проблема с матрицей. Но такое мало вероятно (про проблему с матрицей).